# Delete data from 4 different tables

Tags: postgresql

I've got 4 different tables and I want to delete one row, but it says: id is still referenced from table "parts". How to delete from table Car specific car (for example with id=10) and delete all data without dropping all tables and data? I created tables with Delete Restrict.

```
Table Car:
variables

Table Repair:
variables,
car_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES car(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT 

Table Parts:
variables,
repair_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES repair(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT 

Table Shop:
variables, part_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES part(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Comment: Try to alter your reference with on delete cascade instead of on delete restrict.

Comment: if I change to delete cascade, it will remove specific data referenced to car with id=10 from all tables?

Comment: None of this is relevant to the question, you may as well write pseudo code and just ask what `ON DELETE RESTRICT` does.

Answer (score 1):

you set yourself `ON DELETE RESTRICT` , so it restricts deletion if still referenced. You have to in transaction `drop existing FK` add new with `REFERENCES car(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` then you will be able to delete cascaded...

Comment: so there is no option with "join" and then delete?

Comment: of course there is - I thought you want to get rid of restriction. just delete from each table one by one folowwing referebces

Comment: It can be all in one executed query? Because I'm trying to execute it in one command and still getting errors